# Does every non-empty set of natural numbers have a unique least element?

Tags: order-theory, natural-numbers

First of all, I apologize if this question is too elementary or pedantic. It is usually said that every non-empty set of natural numbers has a least element. However, books usually don't mention if the least element is unique. So, what is the proof that the least element in a non-empty set of natural numbers is unique?

Comment: Because you can't have repeated items in a set.

Comment: What definition of the naturals numbers are you using? Are you allowed to assume that the naturals are totally ordered or just that they are well ordered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ordering on the natural numbers is anti-symmetric, i.e. if $x\leq y$ and $y\leq x$ then $x=y$

Comment: This is not sufficient.  It applies to the rationals and reals as well, neither of which is well-ordered by the usual order.

Comment: @RossMillikan this is sufficient for the question that is asked, namely is "the least element in a non-empty set of natural numbers [...] unique?" In the rationals and the reals, if you hand me non-empty set and tell me it has a least element, that least element is unique by this reasoning

Comment: @RossMillikan As pereptually mentioned, I was only addressing the uniqueness question that the questioner raised